# Azure Storage Performance Queue vs Table

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-queues

I've got a nice logging system I've set up that writes to Azure Table Storage and it has worked well for a long time. However, there are certain places in my code where I need to now write a lot of messages to the log (50-60 msgs) instead of just a couple. It is also important enough that I can't start a new thread to finish writing to the log and return the MVC action before I know the log is successful because theoretically that thread could die. I have to write to the log before I return data to the web user.

According to the Azure dashboard, Table Storage transactions take ~37ms to commit, end to end (E2E), while queues only take ~6ms E2E to commit.

[image]

I'm now considering not logging directly to table storage, and instead log to an Azure Queue, then have a batch job run that reads off the queue and then puts them in their proper place in table storage. That way I can still index them properly via their partition and row keys. I can also write just a single queue message with all of the log entries. So it should only take 6ms instead of (37 * 50) ms.

I know that there are Table Storage batch operations. However, each of the log entries typically goes to different partition, and batch ops need to stay within a single partition.

I know that queue messages only live for 7 days, so I'll make sure I store queue messages in a new mechanism if they're older than a day (if it doesn't work the first 50 times, it just isn't going to work).

My question, then is: what am I not thinking about? How could this completely kick me in the balls in 4 months down the road?

Comment: Azure Table Storage should have 2,000 tps per partition, as per https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/, so your 50-60 tps is way below the limit. Are you using multiple partitions? What size is your VM - could it be possible that you're running into bandwidth limitations for the vm? Are you using a separate Storage Account for your VHDs and for the tables?

Comment: @qualcuno I'm using an app site. So yeah, I would guess the underlying VHD (which I don't actually see/control) would be on a different account. But the queue and table storage are on the same storage account. The storage account is RA-GRS, but the appsite and the main storage location are in same azure region

Comment: What plan are you on? Depending on the size of your App Service Plan (B1, S2, S3, etc) you may possibly be running in limitations of bandwidth. Otherwise, I would considering opening a support ticket to have engineers investigate on this on the backend

Comment: I'm on a single S2 box. I don't think that 2000 tps necessarily means .5 ms E2E. The SLA says that it _can_ take up to 2 seconds per operation (even if there may be 1999 concurrent other operations happening) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/storage/v1_1/

Comment: Apologies for resurrecting a dead post, but I found this to be relevant when it comes to writing multiple Azure Table Storage records via C#: http://robertgreiner.com/2012/06/why-is-azure-table-storage-so-slow/

Comment: @bobtabor thanks for adding to the discussion. FWIW, I've already disabled Nagle a long time ago, so the screenshots about E2E latency already include this change. It'd be interesting to re-enable it for a week to see how the latency changed (presumably upwards, but by how much)

Comment: @viggity So, it's been in excess of 4 months ... did you wind up introducing a queue / web job into the mix?  Did you stick with directly inserting into Azure Table Storage?  Has anything wound up "completely kicking you in the balls"?  Would you do anything differently?  Thank you!

Comment: @BobTabor I did end up using queue to webjob to table storage. Seems to work great. No complaints, I'd recommend it if you need the extra performance